# Can it be shown that `num > 0 && num < denom` is always the same as 0% < num / denom < 100%?

Tags: solidity, integers

In Solidity, I want to check that the numerator and denominator passed to my function evaluate to 0% < num / denom < 100%.

I tried the most direct approach: `num / denom > 0 && num / denom < 1` but e.g. 1% (`1 / 100 > 0 && 1 / 100 < 1`) evaluates to false, because Solidity doesn't have decimals.

My other idea is `num > 0 && num < denom`. Can it be formally proven that that is always the same as 0% < num / denom < 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not worried about the exactly 0% and exactly 100% cases (or alternatively, the `num == 0` and `num == denom` cases), then yes, `num > 0 && num < denom` is correct (with an implied `denom > 1`, anyway).

The proof is fairly simple: `0 < num / denom < 1` can be rewritten as `0 * denom < num < 1 * denom`, which reduces to `0 < num < denom`. This can further be rewritten as `0 < num && num < denom`, which is equivalent to `num > 0 && num < denom`

Answer (score -1):

Please be careful with such things: The mathematical meaning of "0  < num / denom < 1", in the sense of rational or real numbers is different from the meaning in programming languages that deal with integers like Solidity.

For example, if num is 1 and denom is 2, then num / denom will be 0 in Solidity but 0.5 in the mathematical sense and thus larger than zero.

So in short: "num > 0 && num < denom" is not the correct check in Solidity, but it all depends on what you do with this afterwards.

Comment: But that's exactly what is being asked. Why isn't that the correct check in Solidity? Can you formally prove it?